# Object center detection using Convnet is always returning center of image rather than center of object

Tags: python, computer-vision, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I have a small dataset of ~150 images. Each image has an object (rectangle box with white and black color) placed on the floor. The object is same in all images but the pattern of the floor is different. The objective is to train network to find the center of the image. Each image is of dimension `256x256x3`.

`Train_X` is of size `150x256x256x3` and Train_y is of size `150x2` (150 here indicates the total number of images)

I understand 150 images is too small a dataset, but I am ok giving up on some accuracy so I trained data on Conv nets. Here is the architecture of convnet I used

- Conv2D layer (filter size of 32)
- Activation Relu
- Conv2D layer (filter size of 64)
- Activation Relu
- Flattern layer
- Dense(64) layer
- Activation Relu
- Dense(2)
- Activation Softmax
- model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='sgd')

Observation: Trained model always return the normalized center of image 0.5,0.5 as the center of 'object' even on the training data. I was hoping to get center of a rectangular object rather than the center of the image when I run predict function on train_X. Am I getting this output because of my conv layer selections?

Comment: Try switching activation to `sigmoid`. When you use `softmax` you add a spurious condition to your output - mainly - coordinates summing up to `1`.

Comment: I tried softmax as well but the result is same. I am not sure why all the predicted values of train and test set are giving normalized center of image as center of the object.

Comment: `softmax` or `sigmoid`?

Comment: I mean to say I tried using sigmoid as well. Still getting normalized center as predicted output. Tried MSE, ASE as loss functions as well, and still getting same problem

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't mentioned it in the details, the following suggestions (if you haven't implemented them already), could help:

1) Normalizing the input data (say for e.g, if you are working on input images, x_train = x_train/255 before feeding the input to the layer)

2) Try linear activation for the last output layer

3) Running the fitting over higher epochs, and experimenting with different batch sizes

Answer (score 0):

You are basically trying to solve a regression problem. Apart from what you have done, there are few other things that you can try:

1. Use [**ImageAugmentation**](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) technique to generate more data. Also, normalize the images.
2. Make a deeper model with a few more convolution layers.
3. Use a proper **weights initializer** maybe He-normal for the convolution layers.
4. Use [**BatchNormalization**](https://keras.io/layers/normalization/) between layers to make the **mean** and **std** of your filter values equal to 0 and 1 respectively.
5. Use **crossentropy loss** as it helps in better calculation of your gradients. In MSE the gradients become very small over time although it seemed to be preferred for regression problems.
6. Try to change the optimizer to **Adam**.
7. In case, you have a few more classes in your dataset, and you have class imbalance problem, you can use **Focal loss**, a variant of crossentropy loss which penalizes the misclassified labels more than the correctly classified labels. Also, reducing the **batch size** and **Upsampling** should help.
8. Use **Bayesian Optimization** techniques for **hyperparameter** tuning of your model.

A sample model code:

```
with open(os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'mnist.pickle'), 'rb') as fr:
    X_train, Y_train, X_val, Y_val = pickle.load(fr)
X_train = X_train.reshape(60000, 784)
X_val = X_val.reshape(10000, 784)
X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_val = X_val.astype('float32')
X_train /= 255
X_val /= 255
nb_classes = 10
Y_train = to_categorical(Y_train, nb_classes)
Y_val = to_categorical(Y_val, nb_classes)
return X_train, Y_train, X_val, Y_val

def build_model(input_shape, dropout=True):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (5,5), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='valid', input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=1, padding='valid'))
    if dropout:
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='valid'))
    model.add(Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='valid'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=2, padding='valid'))
    if dropout:
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dense(classes, activation='softmax', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
    # optimizer = SGD(lr=0.01, decay-1e-6, momentum=0.9)
    optimizer = Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0.0, amsgrad=False)
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using the "SoftMax" activation in the last layers is the main reason that your network can't perform weakly so you can use Relu or any other linear activation or use non. also I suggest you use PreTrained networks middle output like VGG so you won't need to train the Conv part and just train the dense part. In case of your little data you can use keras image generators to augment more images like below.

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=True,
    featurewise_std_normalization=True,
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)
# compute quantities required for featurewise normalization
# (std, mean, and principal components if ZCA whitening is applied)
datagen.fit(x_train)
# fits the model on batches with real-time data augmentation:
model.fit(datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32),
          steps_per_epoch=len(x_train) / 32, epochs=epochs)
# here's a more "manual" example
for e in range(epochs):
    print('Epoch', e)
    batches = 0
    for x_batch, y_batch in datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32):
        model.fit(x_batch, y_batch)
        batches += 1
        if batches >= len(x_train) / 32:
            # we need to break the loop by hand because
            # the generator loops indefinitely
            break
```

so as a summary just do this:

- **Delete** `Softmax` activation or use Linear ones like `Relu` or `LeakyRelu`.
- Use **Pretrained** network for feature extraction.
- Use **image augmentation** to create more images.